# Polygons for the districts of gulf area countries and middle east?

Tags: polygon, boundaries

I need to find the lowest level possible polygons for a few countries, including KSA, Jordan, UAE, Lebanon...

By lowest level polygons, I mean districts like [this one](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Ishbiliyah,+Riyadh+Saudi+Arabia/@24.7928297,46.7746566,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!1m7!3m6!1s0x3e2f03890d489399:0xba974d1c98e79fd5!2sRiyadh+Saudi+Arabia!3b1!8m2!3d24.7135517!4d46.6752957!3m4!1s0x3e2effd16e4395fd:0xc36b47278526459c!8m2!3d24.7908255!4d46.7913723) and even if smaller

Where can I download or buy this data?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to GIS SE! Please be sure to take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't yet, as it will give you guidelines on how to ask good, effective questions.  In your question, you should indicate what you've done on your own so far to solve this issue. This site should not be treated as the place where your research starts, but is rather where you end up after you've tried everything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the osm file for [whole of asia](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia-latest.osm.pbf) from [this website](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia.html)

[image]

The disadvantage is that it only downloadable in **OSM format**.

Or to download the countries you want one by one [from here](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia.html), although some of the countries you mentioned are missing .

Also [this website](http://gadm.org/country) offers you the data for all countries , so you can choose your countries and download their shape files as it offers the ability to download with many formats.

Comment: Some of the ata from this site is also available as shapefiles (inc. Jordan & Lebanon from the [Asia](http://download.geofabrik.de/asia.html) list).